# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring MVC. I'm facing `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. I have added `stereotype annotations` but still I'm facing same issue.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean found for dependency
>   [com.demo.app.service.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which
>   qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   looking positive replay.

**UserController:**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired(required=true)
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/userSave" },consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveUserDetails(@RequestPart(value="file",required=false) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart("user")User user,
        HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.println("data reached...!");
        String result=userService.saveUserData(user,session);
        return result;

}
```

}

**UserService:**

```
public interface UserService {
     public String saveUserData(User user,HttpSession session);
}
```

**UserServiceImpl:**

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public String saveUserData(User user,HttpSession session){
    String  output;
    Date regDate=new Date();
    user.setRegDate(regDate);
    output= userRepository.saveUserData(user);
    return output;
}
```

}

**UserRepository:**

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class UserRepository  extends BaseRepository{

@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public String saveUserData(User user) {

    final Session session = (Session) getSessionFactory();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query=session.createQuery("UPDATE User set user_Name =:userName,"
                + "reg_Date =:regDate,img_Id=:imgId");
        query.setParameter("userName", user.getUserName());
        query.setParameter("regDate", user.getRegDate());
        query.setParameter("imgId", user.getImgId());
        query.setParameter("emailId", user.getImgId());
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

**spring.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                    ">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.app" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value="html" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/UserDB" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.demo.app.model.User</value>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2097152" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Error:**

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.demo.app.service.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
```

Please help me,

Thank you

Comment: how your component-scan Looks like and what are your package declarations?

Comment: @Jens thank you for your replay. can i post my spring.xml file

Comment: show your controller code where service is injected

Comment: @SagarKadu ya sure i will update my code check it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolved .spring dependency jar file versions are mismatched. all spring dependency versions are same.

```
     <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4):

`@Service("userService")` should be near implementation not interface.

Comment: Then it mean that spring don't create this bean, possible reason that your service is not in component-scan package

Comment: check it once i added component-scan also

Answer (score 2):

Check all the following points :

1 - `@Entity` added to all entities  .

2 - `@Service` added to all DAOs or any other components .

3 - `@RestController` added to all Controllers .

My Error was not added `@Entity` on my entity .

Answer (score 1):

@service annotation use in service implementation, not in interface because interface is only mapping controller to actual service implementation and other logic only...

Answer (score 1):

"No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.demo.app.service.UserService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate."

Above error means UserService bean were not created.
Can you please check whether you've give the correct base package here.

Also can you please change annotation to UserRepository  @Component to @Repository.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't have `@EnableWebSecurity` in this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // add our users for in memory authentication

        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(users.username("john").password("test123").roles("EMPLOYEE"))
                .withUser(users.username("mary").password("test123").roles("MANAGER"))
                .withUser(users.username("susan").password("test123").roles("ADMIN"));
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)  throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/showLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue.

In my case I thought it was the Maven dependencies and updated them and got all my Java files as error.

Finally, after updating all the Maven dependencies and added this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

That works for projects which are Java versions > 9
I was using OpenJDK 11 in my project.
Thanks. Hope it helps.

Happy Coding.